# hierarchical data using HQL/Criteria Java

Tags: jpa, hql, criteria, criteria-api

1. I have table:

   ```
   +----+-------------------+------+-------------------+-------+
   | id | exType            | exId | depType           | depId |
   +----+-------------------+------+-------------------+-------+
   | 1  | Ceo               | 1    | Board Of Director | 1     |
   | 2  | Board Of Director | 1    | Manager           | 4     |
   | 3  | Board Of Director | 1    | Manager           | 5     |
   | 4  | Manager           | 4    | TeamLead          | 1     |
   | 5  | Manager           | 5    | TeamLead          | 2     |
   | 6  | TeamLead          | 1    | Member            | 7     |
   | 7  | TeamLead          | 1    | Member            | 8     |
   | 8  | TeamLead          | 1    | Member            | 9     |
   | 9  | TeamLead          | 1    | Member            | 10    |
   | 10 | TeamLead          | 2    | Member            | 19    |
   +----+-------------------+------+-------------------+-------+
   ```
2. I want all the member's, when I give input as `exType` as **Manager** and `exId` as `4` I want:

   ```
   Member  7
   Member  8
   Member  9   
   Member  10
   ```

   or I want all the member's, when I give input as `exType` as **TeamLead** and `exId` as `1` I want:

   ```
   Member  7
   Member  8
   Member  9
   Member  10
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select depType, depId from table where exType in (Select depType from table where exType='Manager') a and exId in (Select depId from table where exId='4')
```

```
Select depType, depId from table where exType = 'TeamLead' and exId = '1'
```

Comment: Here I am to get only one level , not  completely
or Could you please elaborate above